# Как создать переводы для темы WP

Tags: wordpress, themes, wp-theme

Добрый день. Создали собственную тему на одном языке. Теперь хотим её перевести на другой язык. Для этого хотим использовать lang файлы en_US и ru_RU
В самой теме создали папку lang, туда закачали файлы с созданными переводами 
en_US.mo
en_US.po
ru_RU.mo
ru_RU.po
tmp.pot

Как теперь их подключить к теме? Функционал смены локализации реализуем плагином, поэтому это объяснять не надо.

Пытаюсь вывести что-то вроде

```html
<?php
_e( 'Page not found' )
?>
```

но из русского LANG не подтягивает.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ.
Когда мы подгружаем настройки надо лишь добавить функцию load_theme_textdomain

```html
if ( ! function_exists( 'your_theme_setup' ) ) :

function your_theme_setup() {
  
 load_theme_textdomain( 'your_theme', get_template_directory() . '/lang/' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Для этого хотим использовать lang файлы en_US

Локализация `en_US` - дефолтная в ВП. Для неё, в общем-то не нужно создавать отдельный лангпак. Лучше (нужно?) на англ сразу писать в строках для локализации. :)

Про правильную интернационализацию см: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/

Также стоит посмотреть доклад Сергея Бирюкова: http://wordpress.tv/2016/09/15/sergey-biryukov-i18n-for-plugin-and-theme-developers/